# Comparing two anonymous type arrays and find element Indexes [VB.net]

Tags: arrays, vb.net, linq, vb.net-2010, indexof

I have two anonymous type arrays and they have same values but at different indexes. Now, I want to match them on the basis of these values and make a third array which must contain two columns; indexes of first array elements, indexes of second array elements.I have to do this using LINQ. I have tried doing this but i haven't been successful yet. What am I doing wrong;

```
Dim one = (from test in data select test.AP_real).toarray
dim two = (from test in data2 select test.AP_fake).toarray

dim test = (from a in one join b in two on a.ap_real equals b.ap_fake select array.indexof(a,a.ap_actual),array.indexof(b,b.ap_fake)).toarray
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way I think you can achieve it,
But I'm sure there's a better solution.

What I did was creating an object from each array which holds index and value,
join on the value but take the index to the result object.

Hope this helps.

```
Dim array1 = New List(Of Integer)() From {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}.
    ToArray()

Dim array2 = New List(Of Integer)() From {0, 7, 2, 5}.
    ToArray()

Dim i As Integer

i = 0

Dim array1WithIndexes = array1.
    Select(Function(o)

               Dim result = New With
                            {
                                .Item1Index = i,
                                .Value = o
                            }

               i += 1

               Return result

           End Function).ToList()

i = 0

Dim array2WithIndexes = array2.
    Select(Function(o)

               Dim result = New With
                            {
                                .Item2Index = i,
                                .Value = o
                            }

               i += 1

               Return result

           End Function).ToList()

Dim joinedResult = From item1 In array1WithIndexes
            Join item2 In array2WithIndexes
            On item1.Value Equals item2.Value
            Select item1.Item1Index, item2.Item2Index, item1.Value
```